# A question on entailments in sequents

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory

Suppose $\Gamma\vdash A\vee \Delta$, where as usual $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ are thought of as sets of propositions and the turnstyle is for logical consequence, or entailment.

Given the assumption, may one consider the relation between what is above the line and what is below the line of the sequent $\frac{\Gamma\vdash A, \Delta}{\Gamma\vdash A\vee B, \Delta}$ to be an entailment on a par with - as in, having the same *nature* as - the relation between the left and the right side of the turnstyle in $\Gamma\vdash A\vee \Delta$, or is there something which prohibits such a point of view?

Comment: I know at least one case when it can be devastating:$$\frac A{\Box A}$$

Comment: The horizontal lines I relate to are those of Gentzen's sequents.

Comment: How is this different from the axiom vs rule issue? A lot of rules are sound but axioms are much more powerful.

Comment: "Various sources in the literature claim that the deduction theorem does not hold for normal modal or epistemic logic, ... It is shown here that the apparent problem arises from an objectionable notion of derivability from assumptions in an axiomatic system. ...  the necessitation rule has to be modified in a way that restricts its use to cases in which the premiss does not depend on assumptions ... A necessitation rule with this restriction permits a proof of the deduction theorem in its usual formulation."

https://philpapers.org/rec/HAKDTD

Comment: Of course, but this needs to be stated explicitly, especially if you're doubting modus ponens!

Comment: @François G. Dorais I don't see that doubt about modus ponens is involved here, but a failure of the deduction theorem would pose problems as you and მამუკა ჯიბლაძე may have had in mind, I think. 

As to the other point: For example, I considered $\Gamma, A\vdash \Delta, A$ to be a rule, although it is usually called an "axiom".

Comment: Yes but frequently you also have an axiom $\Box A\to A$; if not interpreting all this carefully you would conclude that under this axiom together with the necessitation rule $A$ and $\Box A$ are equivalent.

Comment: The issue with the necessitation rule is that we don't actually want it as a rule when undertaking conditional modal reasoning, since perhaps we are in a situation where A is true, but not necessary. We use the necessitation rule, rather, as a convenient tool to define modal theories, such as S4, S4.2, S4.3, etc. It is a convenient proof-theoretic way of defining the particular modal theories, not a sound rule of modal reasoning.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins In fact in my head I always translate it to the language of algebras-with-operators. Under this translation, the necessitation rule corresponds to requiring $\Box(\top)=\top$, which one frequently wants to hold in the algebra.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. The paragraph "History of the meaning of sequent assertions" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent is relevant here:

"The assertion symbol in sequents originally meant exactly the same as the implication operator. But over time, its meaning has changed to signify provability within a theory rather than semantic truth in all models.

In 1934, Gentzen did not define the assertion symbol ' ⊢ ' in a sequent to signify provability. He defined it to mean exactly the same as the implication operator ' ⇒ '.

Comment: "Using ' → ' instead of ' ⊢ ' and ' ⊃ ' instead of ' ⇒ ', he wrote: "The sequent A1, ..., Aμ → B1, ..., Bν signifies, as regards content, exactly the same as the formula (A1 & ... & Aμ) ⊃ (B1 ∨ ... ∨ Bν)".[4] (Gentzen employed the right-arrow symbol between the antecedents and consequents of sequents. He employed the symbol ' ⊃ ' for the logical implication operator.)

In 1939, Hilbert and Bernays stated likewise that a sequent has the same meaning as the corresponding implication formula.[5]

In 1944, Alonzo Church emphasized that Gentzen's sequent assertions did not signify provability."

Comment: "Employment of the deduction theorem as primitive or derived rule must not, however, be confused with the use of Sequenzen by Gentzen. For Gentzen's arrow, →, is not comparable to our syntactical notation, ⊢, but belongs to his object language (as is clear from the fact that expressions containing it appear as premisses and conclusions in applications of his rules of inference)."[6]

Numerous publications after this time have stated that the assertion symbol in sequents does signify provability within the theory where the sequents are formulated."

Comment: Curry in 1963,[7] Lemmon in 1965,[2] and Huth and Ryan in 2004[8] all state that the sequent assertion symbol signifies provability. However, Ben-Ari (2012, p. 69) states that the assertion symbol in Gentzen-system sequents, which he denotes as ' ⇒ ', is part of the object language, not the metalanguage.[9]

Comment: "According to Prawitz (1965): "The calculi of sequents can be understood as meta-calculi for the deducibility relation in the corresponding systems of natural deduction."[10] And furthermore: "A proof in a calculus of sequents can be looked upon as an instruction on how to construct a corresponding natural deduction."[11] In other words, the assertion symbol is part of the object language for the sequent calculus, which is a kind of meta-calculus, but simultaneously signifies deducibility in an underlying natural deduction system."

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Interesting - I think I disagree that necessitation is merely a convenient proof-theoretic way of defining modal theories. It's true of course that $P\rightarrow \square P$ is not sound, but the rule "from $\vdash P$, conclude $\vdash \square P$" is sound, and I would argue that it is a crucial part of modal reasoning. I think it's more natural to present System K by: Propositional logic + (1) from $P\vdash Q$, conclude $\square P\vdash \square Q$ + (2) $\vdash \square\bigwedge_{i=1}^n P_i\leftrightarrow \bigwedge_{i=1}^n \square P_i$.

Comment: (continued) Now (1) and (2) are equivalent to (K) and Necessitation over propositional logic [Note that (2) includes the case $n = 0$: $\vdash \square \top \leftrightarrow \top$], and I would argue that (1) and (2) are core features of modal reasoning ($\square$ preserves sequents and conjunctions, i.e. $\square$ is  functorial and product-preserving) and hence (K) and Necessitation must also capture something fundamental about modal reasoning.

Comment: The comment about "from ⊢P, conclude ⊢□P" is exactly what I meant by using it to define a modal theory. In modal reasoning, we generally have premises, and in this context Nec is unsound, and this is why I find Nec offputting as a rule. For defining the modal theories, I'd rather not do so with a proof system at all, but semantically. The most natural definition of K is: the validities of propositional Kripke models.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins In a Kripke model, if $\vDash\varphi$ then $\vDash\Box\varphi$

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins It may interest some here that the philosopher David Kaplan, in the interesting work Demonstratives, defended a view along the lines that "I am here now" is an analytical truth which does not express a necessary truth. 

I found it worthwhile to point out that Sara Negri and Raul Hakli in the paper I linked to above provide the rule $LR\square:$ $\frac{\Gamma\vdash A}{\square\Gamma, \Theta\vdash \Delta, \square A}$. Ordinary necessitation follows as a special case if A is derivable from no assumptions.